# Dynamic table names in Yii2

Tags: php, oop, yii2

I have a Yii2 Model that uses multiple tables with the same structure. The table names will change according to the user logged in and the table names are very unique and depends on the username .How will i assign this table name to the model dynamically?I have done this so far.

In my model:

```
    protected $table;

    public function __construct($table)
    {
    $this->table='custom_risk_assignment_table';//logic to obtain the table name goes here
    }

    public static function tableName()
    {
    return $this->table;
    }
```

But by doing so results in error `Using $this when not in object context` since `function tableName()` is a `static` function.

How can i do it then?Any help appreciated.Thanks in advance!

**Edit:A detailed picture**

Say i have a user from the company ABC. I have so many processes in my application,say PQR is one of them. If user from the company ABC logins and choose the process PQR,i need to create a table ABC_PQR in my database if not exists or load the table if it is already created. I need this table name into my model. Similarly may users and many processes are there.What will be the best approach to manage the database.

Comment: Using different tables in the same database depending on some runtime check is possibly the worst way to do this. How many distinct table names are we talking about?

Comment: @Jon Dumbing all the data in a single table will take more time to query! I have more than 12 custom tables for a single user.

Comment: Have you considered separate databases? Anyway, the best argument that this is not something you should be happy to do is the number of issues you will be facing.

Comment: Then the number of database will be equal to the number of users right?So i need a common database to manage all users + custom databases. Will Yii2 support this?

Comment: I have no idea because what "this" is will depend a lot on the specifics of your app. But it's something to think about.

Comment: I also added an answer that shows how you can do what you set out to do without hacks. The downside is that you will need to create a separate class for each possible table, which is verbose.

Answer (score 5):

Since `tableName` is a static method (exactly what the error message says) you don't have access to non-static properties. (you can't use `$this` keyword)

So you'd have to declare a static property:

```
protected static $table;

public function __construct($table)
{
    self::$table = $table;
}

public static function tableName()
{
    return self::$table;
}

/* UPDATE */
public static function setTableName($table)
{
    self::$table = $table;
}
```

UPDATE:

Ok my fault. The constructor will not get called if you call a static method like `updateAll`, `find` etc. And `$table` will not get set. So you have different options.

1. Manually call the constructor before using the static db manipulation methods.
2. Add a static setter to the model like `public static function setTableName($tableName)` and call it on every successful login.

Comment: error gone! But `return self::$table` is still empty. :-(

Comment: Actually I can't automate it on every successful login since i hav got a lot of custom tables.I need to assign the table only if user needs it!

Comment: Like Jon noted your approach seems not be the best idea. Can you elaborate a little more why 1 table is slow and why you think you need personal tables for your users?

Comment: :My application is more like an analytical application and it requires a huge number of calculations and interaction of table data. Thats why i thought of storing each users data separately so that the analytics will be easy and fast.

Comment: It's a new information that you will create new tables dynamically. The whole thing gets more dubiuos. I just can't imagine that you have so many data that you can't handle it in one table. Why not try the normal ways to speed things up like: indeces, caching, views, stored procedures etc.

Comment: Hmm..i ll consider redesigning my database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not post your db model, so that we can have a look?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get out of this situation without hacks is to not vary the return value of `tableName` but instead use different classes for the different tables. Those classes would differ only in the implementation of `tableName`:

```
abstract class Foo extends ActiveRecord
{
    // your existing code goes here

    abstract function tableName();
}

class FooOne extends Foo
{
    function tableName() { return 'table1'; }
}

class FooTwo extends Foo
{
    function tableName() { return 'table2'; }
}
```

Then, at some appropriate place in your app you would decide which table you want to use and remember what the model for that table is. Something like:

```
if ($username == "anne") {
    $fooModel = new FooOne();
}
else if ($username == "bob") {
    $fooModel = new FooTwo();
}
```

After this you can simply use `$fooModel` as the call target and the query will affect the appropriate table automatically. For example:

```
$foos = $fooModel::findAll();
```

Comment: Thanks jon.But I am sorry that i could'nt understand your point. Bcoz,here also i need to get the unique table names right?my table names will start with username.How will i change it?Also since my users are more than 100,is it practical to write differnt classes for everyone of them?

Comment: @DencyGB: That's the kind of important detail that should come together with the question. I can't say what the best solution would be (indeed, this one won't be practical), but I can say this: you are going into fancy stuff territory. **Be careful**.

Comment: :Sorry for not mentioning it in the question.+1 for your suggestions. I really don't noe how to handle this situation or shud i redesign the db or not.Hope someone will share their idea.

Comment: @John: Please see my updated question and kindly help me if you can!

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been going on for a long time, but I just saw this problem and have some ideas, I hope to help later people.

Setting the table name dynamically through the constructor is not friendly. we can bind the table name by setting a factory method, for example:

```
class MyTableModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    protected static $table;

    public static function useTable($table) {
        static::$table = $table;

        return new static();
    }

    public static function tableName() {
        return static::$table;
    }
}
```

When used, bind the table name through the `useTable`, for example:

```
// find
MyTableModel::useTable('tableName1')::find()->where(...)->all(); // use tableName1
MyTableModel::useTable('tableName1')::findAll(); // use tableName1
MyTableModel::useTable('tableName1')::updateAll(); // use tableName1

MyTableModel::useTable('tableName2')::findAll(); // use tableName2

// create 
$table = MyTableModel::useTable('tableName2');
$table->attributes = $attributes;
$table->save()
```

Use the `useTable` method to achieve a fully bound target.

**Note that this is not done with a closure, but instead sets the value of the `MyTableModel::$table` static variable. So calling `useTable` multiple times will use the last set value**