# Yii2 How can I use one active record class and reuse it for multiple tables having same schema

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

If suppose I have 3 tables:

**School** ( id, name, location)

**School_1** ( id, name, location)

**School_2** (id, name, location)

I have a model extending ActiveRecord for School. Can I use the same active record class for School_1 and School_2. Because the table schema is same I don't want to use multiple model classes.

Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be use one table `School` and add field `school_id`? Used many tables with the same structure it is not best practices.

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558694/dynamic-table-names-in-yii2/23561251#23561251

Comment: @vitalik_74: the scenario is School_1 and School_2 would be dynamically generated. So instead of creating a new model class for them isn't it feasible to use the existing School model class. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply override `tableName()`, e.g. for `School_1` :

```
class School1 extends School
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'School_1';
    }
}
```

And if needed (I think so) you can create these classes on the fly using `eval()`.

Comment: that worked! Yes I wanted to create those classes on the fly. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: What about using behaviors?