# Dynamically Selecting Model using a single model

Tags: php, constructor, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii framework.
I want to create a model that dynamically selects the table based on a criteria.
I can extract the criteria and pass it to the table name but I can't return the table.

Example: 
I have two tables, lets say :

```
 2016_17_applicant_data
 2017_18_applicant_data
```

Both the tables have the same structure.

I pass the criteria 2016_17 to the table name and concatenate it.

```
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function tableName($code)
{
    var_dump($code); // it works perfectly. I can get the value as per, but when i make it as table name it gives the error shown below
    return $code."_applicant_data";
}
```

Missing argument 1 for app\modules\module\models\Model::tableName(), called in /Applications/AMPPS/www/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php on line 831 and defined

I need the help to integrate the concept. Anyone can help me to out using the existing method or a with a new approach(most welcomed).

Comment: You made argument `$code` mandatory for `tableName($code)` which does not match with  [ActiveQuery::getPrimaryTable()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveQuery.php#L836). Find other workaround for this. [Help](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/model-for-dynamic-table-name/57443/4)

Comment: Exactly, this is right, what you are saying, but without passing the argument, it wont detect the table

Comment: [Helps :)](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=yii2+dynamic+table+name&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: How you know which table  you need .. ?   .
how do you know if you need 2016_17_applicant_data or 2017_18_applicant_data ?   ..

Comment: declare a static property inside your class `private static $_tableName` set it in a different method as setter function `setTable($code)`, and in `tableName()` just return that private/protected static variable `self::$_tableName` that you are setting in the setter function and remove the parameter, exactly how it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558694/dynamic-table-names-in-yii2) by @bitWorking

Comment: @scaisEdge I will pass the parameter 2016_17, 2017_18 on the link I would create, and i have successfully extract the parameter accordingly. But can't return the table.

Comment: show the code where you build the query  ..  and need  the table